# Ordering in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table and I want to order it according to the '`road_id`' column, BUT at the same time I want that all the rows of same road_id reamin in the order as they are. The following is the table I am referring to:

[image]

Is it possible to do such issue?

Comment: What do you mean "the order that they are"? - rows are not ordered unless you order them. The order they come back in without an `order by` is arbitrary (although usually consistent due to implementation details)

Comment: BUT than I will lose the order of my points column @user1389596

Comment: It looks like these are sequential id's?  If it's auto inserted it should be fine ... id would be the order of the points.

Comment: The OP desires a **stable** sort, such as merge-sort but unlike Quicksort. Presumably there are additonal fields/constraints on the ordering as presented.

Answer (score 6):

There is no "order they are" in SQL.

Data are not ordered unless explicitly selected with `ORDER BY`.

If you want to retain ordering by `id` within same `road_id`, use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        road_id, id
```

Comment: re: "There is no "order they are" in SQL"; not strictly true. while SQL the language does not make a row-order visible, many past implementatons of SQL have. And there may be additional fields that are defining the "order as they are".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: are you suggesting a change to the answer?

Comment: No, just trying to edge your commentary a bit closer to perfection.

Answer (score 3):

**The only way to guarantee order is to use `ORDER BY`.**  If you want results in a specific order, use `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT
  <stuff>
FROM
  <table>
ORDER BY
  road_Id, ID
```

Changing the order in the actual table is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "remaining order" you mean ordering by **id** you will need the following:

`ORDER BY road_id, id`

So your query will be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable ODER BY road_id, id
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?  Can you clarify your answer?

Comment: @bobs - Does it meet with your approval now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do something like the following: (Assuming these records are stored in a SQL database...)

```
SELECT * FROM road_table ORDER BY road_id ASC, id ASC
```

Comment: I have all the column points ordered already. Now I would like to bring the road_id ordered ascending BUT I doubt if it is possible to order the road_id without affecting the points column? @ilikemypizza

Comment: @IT_info - Do you want to produce a view/report or change the data in your original table?

Comment: change the data in my original table. The thing is that all the points are already sorted in a particular way. I would like to sort the road_id without changing the order between the points withhin the same road_id

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a field called "sort_order" and place a number in the column in the order you want the rows to display.